# Unix Shell file not working as expected

Tags: shell, unix, csv

I'm a newbie to Unix shell scripts, and can't understand why this doesn't work as the individual commands do on on the command line. Apologies if its obvious.

I am trying to build a script with some Unix commands, and call it using sh script.sh in Putty.  Here is a sample:

```
echo Carrying out compression
gzip -c file_1.csv > file_1.csv.gz
gzip -c file_2.csv > file_2.csv.gz
gzip -c file_3.csv > file_3.csv.gz
```

Rather than producing the specified named output, I am getting very weird named files eg. 
FTY4WG~7.  That is except for the last one which is named correctly.

If I put a space after each line, it works but I get an error message:
    : No such file or directory

Actually I'm trying to do a whole bunch of stuff (stitching together CSVs as well as compressing them), but if I can crack this simple command I'll probably be able to work it all out.

Thanks for your help!

Ben

Comment: Check that your script does not use DOS line endings.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have this line at the top of the script

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Now execute this command

```
dos2unix <yourfilename>
```

Now do this

```
chmod u+x <urfilename>
```

May be this will do.